# using storyboard how to play AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

I am developing AVAudioPlayer according to my project requirement. In audioplayer iam using storyboard to develope coding.In my audio player using json parser to retrieve the urls from server.And finally gave the connections from first responder to Audioviewcontroller.I Can run the audioplayer. Audioplayer is successfully playing. But view will not be displayed.Blank screen will be displayed. I can drag and drop of all buttons like play button, pause button,forward button and rewind button etc. Those are buttons are drag and drop on AudioviewController. And give the connections also.These are all buttons are not displayed on Audioviewcontroller to play the corresponding song. Plz help me any body whats the problem. I am new to the ios programming.Thanks in Advance...

**Audioviewcontroller.m**

```
-(void)updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)
{
    currentTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)p.currentTime / 60, (int)p.currentTime % 60, nil];
    progressBar.value = p.currentTime;
}

-(void)updateCurrentTime
{
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:self.avPlayer];
}

-(void)updateViewForPlayerState:(AVAudioPlayer *)p
{
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:p];
    if (updateTimer) 
       [updateTimer invalidate];
    if (p.playing) 
    {
        [playButton setImage:(p.playing==YES)? pauseButtonBG:playButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        updateTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:p repeats:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [playButton setImage:(p.playing==YES)? pauseButtonBG:playButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        updateTimer=nil;
    }
}

-(void)updateViewForPlayerStateInBackground:(AVAudioPlayer *)p
{
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:p];
    if (p.playing) 
    {
        [playButton setImage:(p.playing==YES)? pauseButtonBG:playButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [playButton setImage:(p.playing==YES)? pauseButtonBG:playButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

-(void)updateViewForPlayerInfo:(AVAudioPlayer*)p
{
    duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)p.duration / 60, (int)p.duration % 60, nil];
    progressBar.maximumValue = p.duration;
    volumeSlider.value = p.volume;
}

// rewind audio player
-(void)rewind
{
    AVAudioPlayer *p=rewindTimer.userInfo;
    p.currentTime-=SKIP_TIME;
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:p];
}

// forward audio player
-(void)forward
{
    AVAudioPlayer *p=forwardTimer.userInfo;
    p.currentTime+=SKIP_INTERVAL;
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:p];
}

json parser::
-(void)loadData
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.teluguastrology.com"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

// delegate methods in json
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connectiondidReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

{
    [_data setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse called");
}

//connection did receive data
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSMutableData *)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

// connection did finish loading
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
    {
        //NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    }
    else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;

        NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"audio-urls"];

        dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0];
        /* NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);*/
    }

    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Meshamu-Aries"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray);


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
//  [connection release];
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError called");
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    playButtonBG=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_play.png"]init];
    pauseButtonBG=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio_pause.png"]init];
    [playButton setImage:playButtonBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[self registerForBackGroundNotification];
    updateTimer=nil;
    rewindTimer=nil;
    forwardTimer=nil;
    // to adjust the font in label to using following method
    duration.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    currentTime.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    progressBar.minimumValue=0.0;

    _data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    [self loadData];
    backgroundImg=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    backgroundImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImg];    
}

-(void)pausePlaybackForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)p
{
    [p pause];
    [self updateViewForPlayerState:p];
}

-(void)startPlaybackForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)p
{
    if([p play]) 
    {
        [self updateViewForPlayerState:p];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Could not play %@\n", p.url);
}

-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (avPlayer.playing==YES) 
        [self pausePlaybackForPlayer:avPlayer];
    else
        [self startPlaybackForPlayer:avPlayer];
}

-(IBAction)rewindButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(rewindTimer) 
    [rewindTimer invalidate];
    rewindTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:SKIP_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(rewind) userInfo:avPlayer repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)rewindButtonReleased:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(rewindTimer) 
        [rewindTimer invalidate];

    rewindTimer=nil;
}

-(IBAction)forwardButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(forwardTimer) 
        [forwardTimer invalidate];

    forwardTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:SKIP_TIME target:self selector:@selector(forward) userInfo:avPlayer repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)forwardButtonReleased:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(forwardTimer) 
    [forwardTimer invalidate];
    forwardTimer=nil;
}

-(IBAction)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
{
    avPlayer.volume=[sender value];
}

-(IBAction)progressBarMoved:(UISlider *)sender
{
    avPlayer.currentTime=[sender value];
    [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:avPlayer];
}
```

**Audioviewcontroller.h**

```
@interface AudioViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *astroName;
    IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *forwardButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *rewindButton;
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentTime;
    IBOutlet UILabel *duration;
    IBOutlet UISlider *progressBar;
    UIImage *playButtonBG;
    UIImage *pauseButtonBG;
    NSTimer *forwardTimer;
    NSTimer *rewindTimer;
    NSTimer *updateTimer;
    UIImageView *backgroundImg;
    BOOL inBackground;
    NSURLConnection *connect;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSMutableData *downloadData;
    NSMutableString *responseString;
    NSMutableArray *urlsArray;
    NSMutableData  *_data;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary;
}

- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)rewindButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)rewindButtonReleased:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)forwardButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)forwardButtonReleased:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider*)sender;
-(IBAction)progressBarMoved:(UISlider *)sender;
-(void)registerForBackGroundNotification;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *astroName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *playButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *pauseButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *forwardButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton *rewindButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISlider *volumeSlider;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISlider *progressBar;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *currentTime;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *duration;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *updateTimer;
@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL *inBackGround;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *backgroundImg;
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData* responseData;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSData *downloadData;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *responseString;
@property (nonatomic,assign)int selectedIndex;
@end
```

Comment: Do you implement `-(void)loadView` in your AudioViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to comment this line of code. You have added UIImageView to self.view after adding all button. Please add this by using storyboard.

```
//[self.view addSubview:backgroundImg];
```

Good Luck !!